# Jest mocking error with mongoose when using Typescript

Tags: unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

### Jest mocking error with mongoose when using Typescript

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to mock Mongoose in my Jest tests for a Typescript project. Here's the scenario:

#### Problem Description

When running my Jest tests, I receive the following error:

```bash
src/controllers/user.controller.ts:667:38 - error TS2339: Property 'execPopulate' does not exist on type 'Promise<IUser & Document<any, any, any> & { _id: any; }>'.
```

#### Project Configuration

##### `package.json`

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "6.0.8",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.6"
  }
}
```

##### Jest Config (`jest.config.ts`)

```js
import type { Config } from "jest";

const config: Config = {
  verbose: true,
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // Your module mappings
  },
  collectCoverageFrom: ["src/**/*.ts"],
  coverageDirectory: "jest-coverage",
  coverageProvider: "v8",
  coverageReporters: ["json", "lcov", "text", "clover"],
};

export default config;
```

#### Relevant Code Snippets

##### User Controller (`src/controllers/user.controller.ts`)

```js
import fs from "fs";
import { Document, LeanDocument, Types, UpdateQuery } from "mongoose";
import { ... } from "~/models";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import { ... } from "~/types";
import { ... } from "~/validators";
import { ... } from "~/errors";
import { ... } from "~/configs";
import { ... } from "./credentials.controller";
import { ... } from "./connection.controller";
import { ... } from "./message.controller";
import { ... } from "helpers/utility.helpers";
import { ... } from "./activity.controller";
import { ... } from "./admin-configuration.controller";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import { ... } from "~/lib";
import { ... } from "lib/process-image-job-queue.lib";
import { ... } from "~/helpers";
import { ValidationError } from "yup";

export const createUser = async (
  createUserProps: CreateUserEKYC | CreateUserManual,
  _io?: Server
): Promise<
  LeanDocument<IUser & Document> & { properties: (IProperty & Document)[] }
  > => {
    const user = await xxx.findById(mongooseId);
    //..
    await user.populate("xxx").execPopulate(); // <----- Test does not recognize this
    //..
};
```

##### User Controller Test (`tests/unit/controllers/user.controller.spec.ts`)

```js
import * as UserController from "controllers/user.controller";

jest.mock("mongoose");

describe("User Controller", () => {
  it("should create a user", async () => {
    // Test logic
  });
});
```

#### Request

Could someone please guide me on how to properly mock Mongoose in my Jest tests for a Typescript project to resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

#### Additional Informations

If uncomment the `jest.mock("mongoose");` line, I get the following error:

```bash
❯ yarn test:unit tests/unit/controllers/user.controller.spec.ts
yarn run v1.22.21
$ jest tests/unit/controllers/user.controller.spec.ts
 FAIL  tests/unit/controllers/user.controller.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Types')

       6 |   propValue: { type: String, required: true },
       7 |   propLabel: { type: String, required: true },
    >  8 |   user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
         |                        ^
       9 |   verified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
      10 |   value: { type: Number },
      11 |   matchString: { type: String },

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/models/property.model.ts:8:24)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/models/index.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app-events/batch.events.ts:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app-events/index.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongodb/src/mongo_types.ts:12:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:46:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongodb/src/sessions.ts:38:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongodb/src/cursor/abstract_cursor.ts:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongodb/src/index.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/binary.js:8:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/index.js:7:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:7:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mongoose/index.js:9:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/models/access-level.model.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/validators/user.validators.ts:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/validators/index.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/configs/environment.config.ts:16:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/configs/index.ts:1:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.517 s
Ran all test suites matching /tests\/unit\/controllers\/user.controller.spec.ts/i.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I've tried various approaches

- using jest.spyOn for model methods
- jest.mocked(mongoose, {shallow: true|false})
  but the error persists.

#### Expected Behavior

Tests should run successfully without any TypeScript errors related to Mongoose.